# SQL - Adding values from same column of different IDs

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

I have 2 tables product and inventory as shown below.

> Product:

```
Product_ID     Product_Description    Price
100            Computer               30
200            Laptop                 50
300            Printer                10
```

> Inventory:

```
Product_ID   Stock
100          40
200          15
300          50
```

From these both tables, I need a query to list Product ID, Product Description and quantity which has the maximum number of stock and add the stock of laptop to the display.

> Expected Output:

```
Product_ID   Product_Description   Stock
300          Printer               65
```

The 65 is the result of 50 for printer & 15 for laptop.

**Could you please help with a query for this at the earliest?**

Comment: What if Laptop has the maximum number of stock? Do you want it doubled?

Comment: yes. thats the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `MAX()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT p.Product_ID, p.Product_Description, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.Product_Description = 'Laptop' THEN i.Stock END) + 
       MAX(i.Stock) Stock
FROM Product p INNER JOIN Inventory i
ON i.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
```

This code relies in SQLite's feature to return the row that contains the max value (in this case the last defined max).

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2568d184e7fb03c5c6e7fc3bdac4a237).
Results:

| Product_ID | Product_Description | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | Printer | 65 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  This uses a trick to whittle the data down to two rows, add up the stock using window functions and then chooses only one row for the non-laptop row (if any).

```
select p.*, sum(stock) over ()
from (select s.*, row_number() over (order by stock desc) as seqnum
      from stock s
     ) s join
     product p
     on p.product_id = s.product_id
where s.seqnum = 1 or p.product_description = 'Laptop'
order by s.seqnum
limit 1;
```